# CopyFromRecordset copies & pastes in same sheet only first one row paste even though multiple records are present in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, adodb

I have an Excel sheet containing table like data

```
Sub SQLQUERY()

Dim QUERY As String

Dim ExcelCn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim RS As New ADODB.Recordset
SourcePath = "C:\Users\negi_tech\Desktop\sqltable.xlsx"





ExcelCn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
               "Data Source=" & SourcePath & ";" & _
               "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
QUERY = "select * from [Sheet2$] WHERE [Type]='RV'"
RS.CursorType = ADODB.CursorTypeEnum.adOpenKeyset
RS.Open QUERY, ExcelCn
RS.MoveLast
RS.MoveFirst
Range("A2:BT50000").ClearContents
Sheet2.Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset RS
```

I am copying data from same sheet and then i am clearing all contents except headers and then pasting recordset in same sheet but it pasting only first row.
but when i am pasting same recordset into other sheet then it pasting all records

Please let me know why other records not copied into recordset?

Comment: what is the active sheet when you run this?

Comment: FYI there's no need to perform the movelast/movefirst here.

Comment: @tim williams-sheet2

Comment: Can you try not specifying the [CursorType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/cursortype-property-ado?view=sql-server-2017) or choose `adOpenStatic`?